# FastAPI Retrieving User Data

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I'm pretty new at creating APIs, so I'm confused on what to search to get my desired outcome. So, essentially, I am creating an application where when users sign up, they have to input their name, email, and password. I want to store their data into a database (which I have as an array right now). I am able to create a Post request where I can add a new user. However, I feel like this isn't very applicable as I am manually inserting these values. What should I be searching/potential resources to look at so that I can input the user's responses of their name, email, and password? Thank you for your help.

This is my main.py thus, far for context:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

data = []
class User(BaseModel):
  userID: int
  name: str
  email: str
  password: str

# get every user
@app.get("/users")
async def get_users():
  return data

#get specific user
@app.get("/users/{user_id}")
async def get_a_user(user_id: int):
  return data[user_id - 1]

#add user
@app.post("/users")
async def add_user(user: User):
  data.append(user.dict())
  return data[-1]
```

Comment: Do you mean what to build so a normal user can sign up? With, say, a web form?

Answer (score 1):

You can read, study, and re-use the templated fullstack project from the developer of `FastAPI` [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql).

You can follow ALL of the tutorials over at [the FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

Your question is a bit too broad to answer, other than handing you the two main resources I used myself.

To sum up the process (more or less) in a few steps:

- your fastapi endpoint receives a `schema` ([pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/)) from the frontend
- the endpoint sends that schema to the database layer
- the database layer deals with modifying that data into database-acceptable data (essentially pydantic <-> [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/))
- sqlalchemy then sends that data to the database

Pretty much the same for retrieving data from the database:

- fastapi endpoint receives a request for data
- the query is passed onto sqlalchemy
- sqlalchemy returns an sqlalchemy `model`, that is transformed into a pydantic `schema`
- this schema is then returned to the frontend that knows how to display it to the user

Comment: ty the information is very insightfull! I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a user management system, it is important to pay attention into CSRF and XSS attacks:

> CSRF is an attack against a web application in which the attacker
> attempts to trick an authenticated user into performing a malicious
> action.
>
> XSS attacks are a type of injection where malicious scripts are
> injected into the client-side, usually to bypass the browser's
> same-origin policy.

From [testdrinve.io](http://testdriven.io)

There are some good examples if you want to create an auth function with good pratices:

- If you want to store user`s credentials on Non-relational database like MongoDB, you can clone [this project from testdriven.io author](https://github.com/Youngestdev/fastapi-mongo) or [this one from FARM creator](https://github.com/aaronbassett/FARM)
- If you want to combine Mongodb with a frontend framework like react, follow [this one](https://github.com/aaronbassett/FARM-starter)
- If you want to store user credentials on relational Databases, you can check
  [Full Stack FastAPI and PostgreSQL](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql) - Base Project Generator - Full stack, modern web application generator, which includes FastAPI, PostgreSQL, Docker, Celery, Vue frontend, automatic HTTPS and more (developed by the creator of FastAPI, Sebastián Ramírez).